# Converting package files to drls

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I am using Drools 5.5.0 ,I have converted all my rules which are in drls into package files(.pkg files) and used them in the needed places. Now I need to know about whether it is possible to convert the package files back into the rules in drl format. Or Can we convert that pkg files into any other rule formats.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Guvnor?  From it you can pull your rulebase down in either format.  Keep in mind that some assets (like bpmn processes) aren't represented in the DRL (so as long as you haven't added any of those assets, going from pkg->drl is still doable).